# GWT 2.7: Return long from JSNI best Practice

Tags: java, javascript, html, gwt

Using GWT 2.7 I store and retrieve long values in JavaScript like in the following code:

```
private final native void setTime(Long time) /*-{
  return this.myLong;
}-*/;

private final native Long getTime() /*-{
  return this.myLong;
}-*/;

private void start() {
  Date date = new Date();
  long time = date.getTime();
  setTime(time);

  long time2 = getTime();
}
```

Note: I can always be sure that the long values in the JavaScript part are not changed because these values are just stored and retrieved from a Database in JavaScript.

**Is this the best way to put long values in and from JavaScript? Would it be better to use double values and then cast to long?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add to Chri's answer, JavaScript can't actually track the full value of a `long`! The most precise number it can track is the equivalent of a Java `double` (64-bit IEEE 754 floating point), and there are some legal values that when cast to `double` and back again, are no longer the same number!

If you are only reading the property *and* you don't care if you have enough precision to actually store it, the unsafe long annotation will work. Use double if you can, or use String if you want a db ID or whatever that doesnt change you when you look at it funny through JS...

Comment: So you mean that when I need precision I should return a String and cast it to long?

Comment: String can't be cast to a long, you'll need to *parse* to a long, but yes, that can work. But if you aren't actually doing long math with the values, just leave it a string - it'll be faster, and is probably all you needed in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

If you are only reading the property then this will work for you.

```
@UnsafeNativeLong
public final native long getValuePropertyLong(String key) /*-{
    return this.value[key];
}-*/;
```

Here you can find more info
http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsJSNI.html

> The Java long type cannot be represented in JavaScript as a numeric
>   type, so GWT emulates it using an opaque data structure. This means
>   that JSNI methods cannot process a long as a numeric type. The
>   compiler therefore disallows, by default, directly accessing a long
>   from JSNI: JSNI methods cannot have long as a parameter type or a
>   return type, and they cannot access a long using a JSNI reference. If
>   you find yourself wanting to pass a long into or out of a JSNI method,
>   here are some options:
>       For numbers that fit into type double, use type double instead of type long.
>       For computations that require the full long semantics, rearrange the code so that the computations happen in Java instead of in
>   JavaScript. That way they will use the long emulation.
>       For values meant to be passed through unchanged to Java code, wrap the value in a Long. There are no restrictions on type Long with JSNI
>   methods.
>       If you are sure you know what you are doing, you can add the annotation com.google.gwt.core.client.UnsafeNativeLong to the method.
>   The compiler will then allow you to pass a long into and out of
>   JavaScript. It will still be an opaque data type, however, so the only
>   thing you will be able to do with it will be to pass it back to Java.